# Dynamically add a url to string with easybutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to add a url to a string with easybutton.js. I am using leaflet.js obviously. It currently works fine like this

```
var operator = L.easyButton('<img src="img/myimage.jpg">', function(btn, map){
    var destination = [window.my_lat, window.my_lng];
      map.flyTo(destination, 16, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 2 // in seconds
          });
}).addTo(map);
```

But if I try this it doesnt pass the variale? :

```
var myimg = "newimage";

var operator = L.easyButton('<img src="img/"+myimg+".jpg">', function(btn, map){
    var destination = [window.my_lat, window.my_lng];
      map.flyTo(destination, 16, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 2 // in seconds
          });
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Because your string delimiter is single quotes, not double quotes.  So it's treating it as a literal.

Comment: I have same problem with var operatorIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: 'location-pin',
    html: '<img src="/img/myimage.jpg"><div class="pin"></div><div class="pulse"></div>',
    iconSize: [30, 30],
    iconAnchor: [18, 30]
  }); So how do I fix it, I have tried adding whole thing to a variable and adding it but no good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake with your string definition. In HTML you can use
- "Double Quotes"
- 'Single Quotes"
- `tilde`

You should change your code to the below. 
    var myimg = "newimage";

```
var operator = L.easyButton("<img src='img/"+myimg+".jpg'>", function(btn, map){
    var destination = [window.my_lat, window.my_lng];
      map.flyTo(destination, 16, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 2 // in seconds
          });
}).addTo(map);
```

You of course could also try:

```
//Using Single Quotes
'<img src="img/'+myimg+'.jpg">'
//Interpolation
`<img src="img/${myimg}.jpg'>`
//Ignoring HTML quotes altogether
"<img src=img/"+myimg+".jpg>"
```

Comment: if I try var operator = L.easyButton("<img src='img/"+window.driver+".jpg'>", function(btn, map){ I get undefinded.jpg

Comment: What is the window.driver variable equal to? Can you try `console.info('img/"+window.driver+".jpg')`?

Comment: Yes I did not have it defined before I set it, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I think the quotes are the problem. Instead of

```js
'<img src="img/"+myimg+".jpg">'
```

It should be

```js
'<img src="img/' + myimg + '.jpg">'
```